# The laptop screen goes black after 6 seconds. What can I do?

Tags: laptop, lcd

I was given a [Dell Latitude D-610](http://www.amazon.fr/Dell-Latitude-Ordinateur-portable-Profesionnel/dp/B004UKUHN6) today that have a strange display problem : when the computer boot, screen goes black after 6 seconds (delay after which I can still see images, provided light is at the right angle). When such a thing happen, I can get an image again by simply closing the laptop and opening it again.

So. What can I do to have the screen working again?

- opening it and finding in the cable mess which one is responsible for the neon to turn off?
- considering it lost and cannibalize its parts?

**EDIT** Indeed, according to Jeff comment, the **symptom** is screen backlight turning off. But, as all House MD viewers know, it's not Lupus ... err, I mean the cause *could* be software, hardware and its multiple variations.

Comment: sounds like a backlight problem, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, most likely this is caused by a faulty inverter, and that needs to be replaced. I did not find it to be very expensive.

Comment: by not very expensive, you mean what price range ? and is it Dell specific ?

Comment: It is not Dell specific. I think the last time cost me around 20 dollars, but that may not be the same for you. Best to check the stores near you.